# Cleaning signal, what do you think?

Tags: signal, filter, noise

Could you check my schematics? **especially the high pass's polarized capacitor**.

So I have this signal, coming from an optical sensor, it's small and dirty.
In it's "original" form the signal looks like a continuous 3V tension.

And nom the same output in AC mode :

[image]

I want to exploit this signal with a microcontroller, so first I'm going to put a high pass at 0.001Hz to get it like in the AC mode, then I'm going to put it through a low pass a 7Hz to remove those parasite and finally I'll amplify it 11 times.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "get it like in the AC mode"? I don't see any reason to have the HP filter there if you're going into a micro with your current circuit.

Comment: I don't know the english term, center it toward 0V, it's because of the amplification, 11*3V = 33V

Comment: I think that correct English term would be to remove DC bias, bu I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @sliders_alpha I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. What's the frequency range which is of interest to you? Also I don't think that you're going to get 33 V from that. If the oscilloscope picture is correct, you have around 40 mV of signal around the zero volt line. If you amplify that 11 times, you'd get 440 mV, which will still be centered around 0 V.

Comment: @sliders_alpha  Next, if you want to use a microcontroller, you should set the signal to be on the middle of it's analog reference voltage, so that the analog to digital converter can get the negative part as well.

Comment: The osciloscope is in CA mode = AC in english, the DC bias has been removed, without a high pass it's not cetered around 0V but 3V.

Comment: A high pass filter with a 0.001 Hz knee frequency will pass a lot of short-term DC drifts. 0.001 Hz means only "one cycle per 1000 seconds, which is more than 15 minutes! So for instance fluctuations on the order of, say, one to two minutes will go through the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify your approach a bit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foM14Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(N.B. The values given are exact. They can be substituted for standard values in exchange or performance, or multiple components put in series/parallel to get the exact values.)

Add the gain stage first. The amplifier has an AC gain of a bit less than 11, but 1 at DC. This will maintain your DC offset for the ADC without it getting amplified. R1 and C1 still form a high pass filter, which is why the AC gain decreased slightly. AC gain can be added my increasing R2.

The second stage is an active second order low pass filter implemented using the [Sallen-Key topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology). Corner frequency is determined by \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$ where \$R=R_3=R_4\$ and \$C=C_2=C_3\$. I think you'll benefit from the more aggressive roll off of the second order filter vs. the first.

Comment: Didn't touch electronics in 4 years, totally forgot that you could make a high pass with amplification. awesome, thanks

Comment: Matt, the high-pass filter (R1, C1) you've got is for 1Hz not 0.001Hz and incidentally, you haven't mentioned the problem with power rail biasing problems in the OP's circuit. Also, have you considered the Q of the 2nd order LPF may enhance artifacts in the signal that may not maintain "heartbeat" shape - I'm sure it'll be OK but it's worth mentioning just in case there is an algorthm in code that is expecting the signal to be a particular shape.

Comment: I'm leaving the high pass alone. It already had an extreme rise time as it was, making it a factor of 1000 worse would be unacceptable. I am making a few assumptions. OP says "In it's "original" form the signal looks like a continuous 3V tension." I take that to mean there is already 3Vdc there, and I'm just leaving it alone, no biasing needed. Not enough is known about the micro/ADC set up to know if anything else needs to be done. I took the lazy way out with Q since signal appears to be much slower than the filter corner frequency. If it's an issue, we'll deal with it later.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to apply a small negative supply to pin 4 of the op-amps or you'll only be amplifying half the waveform.

I also think that the third stage from R2 to the present output should be your input stage and this can be followed by C1 and R1. If you must, apply an output buffer here to preserve the impedance of R1.

Always best to amplify up front for best signal to noise ratio.